# save images in sql server DB with button click

Tags: vb.net

i m using asp.net2008 with vb at back end language . i want to upload image file in the sql server DB in order to keep the record in the database. when i click on save button. and also want to show the save image data in the grid view table.with download option available on it plz help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

Nota :

Adjust your query

Adjust your parameter value (Byte)

Adjust your connection

```
        Dim connetionString As String
        Dim connection As SqlConnection
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim sql As String

        connetionString = "......."
        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)

        sql = "...."
        Try
            connection.Open()

            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarBinary)

            Dim image As [Byte]()
            cmd.Parameters("@Name").Value = image

            adapter.InsertCommand = cmd
            adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Image inserted !! ")

        Catch ex As Exception
            ......
        End Try
```

Comment: can we add virtual keyboard in asp.net page?? n how

Comment: how to create verification ram dam key in asp.net for secure login

Comment: Please @Jay you can create another question, because comment must be in relation with question in order to avoid confusion